# How to customize only one option from react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm working with [react-select](https://react-select.com/) and I want to customize only one option from the drop-down. Is there such an opportunity? I would like to do something like:

```
const CustomOption = ({ innerRef, innerProps, data }) => data.custom
    ? (<div ref={innerRef} {...innerProps} >I'm a custom link</div>)
    : defaultOne //<--- here I would like to keep default option

    <ReactSelect
        components={{ Option: CustomOption }}
        options={[
            { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
            { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
            { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
            { custom: true },
    ]}
/>
```

Any thoughts how to achive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your feeling is good, you can achieve your goal with the following way:

```
const CustomOption = props => {
  const { data, innerRef, innerProps } = props;
  return data.custom ? (
    <div ref={innerRef} {...innerProps}>
      I'm a custom link
    </div>
  ) : (
    <components.Option {...props} />
  );
};

const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" },
  { custom: true }
];

function App() {
  return <Select components={{ Option: CustomOption }} options={options} />;
}
```

The important thing to notice is to pass the entire `props` property to the `components.Option` to have the default behaviour.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8ln4vnr1v2).